# What is the difference between map, each, and collect?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

In Ruby, is there any difference between the functionalities of `each`, `map`, and `collect`?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`each` is different from `map` and `collect`, but `map` and `collect` are the same (technically `map` is an alias for `collect`, but in my experience `map` is used a lot more frequently).

`each` performs the enclosed block for each element in the (`Enumerable`) receiver:

```
[1,2,3,4].each {|n| puts n*2}
# Outputs:
# 2
# 4
# 6
# 8
```

`map` and `collect` produce a new `Array` containing the results of the block applied to each element of the receiver:

```
[1,2,3,4].map {|n| n*2}
# => [2,4,6,8]
```

There's also `map!` / `collect!` defined on `Array`s; they modify the receiver in place:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.map {|n| n*2} # => [2,4,6,8]
puts a.inspect  # prints: "[1,2,3,4]"
a.map! {|n| n+1}
puts a.inspect  # prints: "[2,3,4,5]"
```

Comment: map is the community-choosen version https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#map-fine-select-reduce-size

Answer (score 24):

`Each` will evaluate the block but throws away the result of `Each` block's evaluation and returns the original array.

```
irb(main):> [1,2,3].each {|x| x*2}
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

`Map`/`collect` return an array constructed as the result of calling the block for each item in the array.

```
irb(main):> [1,2,3].collect {|x| x*2}
=> [2, 4, 6]
```