# What is an elegant and concise way of iterating over multiple arrays in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops

The thing I love about Ruby is its elegance: if we use `inject` or `map` along with `take_while` and `select`, we can chain blocks together to achieve a lot while writing little.

Sticking with the idea of single line solutions, how would one write a nested `for` loop in Ruby without writing the entire nested `for` loop? I feel it must be possible, I just can't for the life of me figure out what it is. I am looking for something like this:

```
10.times {|a| 10.times {|b| a*b}}
```

The only solution I can come up with that is at all elegant is nested `for` loops.  Does anyone have a better solution?

```
array = []
for a in (1..10)
  for b in (1..10)
    array << a*b
  end
end
```

Comment: "how would one write a nested for loop in ruby without writing the entire nested for loop"? You have to define the loop somehow. You can't define an incomplete loop and have Ruby run it because it would be a syntax error.

Comment: The code in the answer above contains parse error: the parser will see the `<<a*b` string as HEREDOC syntax instead of `<<` and then `a*b`. A single space is required between them to separate the tokens and avoid the parse error.

Comment: @SasQ good point, fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array has some cool methods.

```
 Array(1..10).repeated_permutation(2).map {|a, b| a*b }
```

`#repeated_permutation` will take an array and generate an array of all permutations of that array of a given length (2, in this case), permitting for repetition (ie, `[1,1]`). We can then just map the product of each pair into a final array.

You can generalize this by using `inject(:*)`. This will take the resultant permutations and multiply all the elements of each. For example, to generate `(1*1*1*1)..(10*10*10*10)` (resulting in an output set of 10,000 elements!):

```
Array(1..10).repeated_permutation(4).map {|v| v.inject :*}
```

Comment: It's an effective trick, but somehow, `#repeated_permutation` is not meant for this. +1 for teaching the noobs the method, but please, don't use it like this.

Comment: Your Matrix solution is more code, is an order of magnitude slower, and uses nearly twice as much RAM to achieve the same result. For a square matrix, `#repeated_permutation` is just fine.

Comment: this is the kind of thing I was looking for, thanks for teaching me a cool new trick!

Answer (score 4):

```
(1..10).to_a.product((1..10).to_a).map { |a,b| a*b }
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-product

Comment: @BorisStitnicky would you consider this to be more efficient than the repeated_perutation method above? I would assume it would be slower given the intermedite arrays it would be creating and then flattening.

Comment: Benchmarking shows that #repeated_permutation is indeed faster and more efficient, likely for the reasons you guessed. It's effectively `x.product(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

> The only solution I can come up with that is at all elegant is nested for loops

`for-in` loops call `each()` on the object to the right of `in`, so rubyists don't use `for-in` loops--they call `each()` directly on the object:

```
array = []

(1..10).each do |a|
  (1..3).each do |b|
    array << a*b
  end
end
```

> Sticking with the idea of single line solutions

Doing that will nearly guarantee you don't write elegant ruby code--just look at the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = (1..10).map {|a| (1..10).map {|b| a*b}}.flatten
```

Comment: ahh, this is what I was originally trying to do, made me realise I should pay attention to the difference between [map and each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429034/what-is-the-difference-between-map-each-and-collect) can anyone explain this though: 

`(1..10).each {|a|a}
 => 1..10 `

Comment: `#each` will return the original object passed to it after iteration (in this case, a range). `#map` will collect the results of the block into an array and return it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at all the answers to this question, I don't feel any of them appear more "elegant" or easier to read than the OP's nested `for` loops. If you want a less verbose notation for nested iteration, I don't think you'll do better than defining your own shorthand. Something like:

```
 module Enumerable
   def combinations(*others)
     return enum_for(:combinations,*others) if not block_given?
     return if self.empty?
     if others.empty?
       self.each { |x| yield [x] }
     else
       others.first.combinations(*others.drop(1)) { |a| self.each { |x| yield (a + [x]) }}
     end
   end
 end
```

Having defined this utility method, you can write your example of nested iteration as:

```
array = []
(1..10).combinations(1..10) { |a,b| array << a*b }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if my invocation of `enum_for` is quite right, I'd have to check. If anyone else knows the right way, please edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
(1..10).inject([]) { |result,a| result + (1..10).to_a.map { |b| a*b } }
```

Or

```
def arithmetic(range, &block)
  range.inject([]) { |result,a| result + range.to_a.map { |b| block.call(a,b) } }
end

range = (1..10)
arithmetic(range) {|a,b| a*b }
arithmetic(range) {|a,b| a+b }
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing problems like these, remember your high school calculus:

```
a = *1..10
b = *1..10
require 'matrix'

Matrix.column_vector( a ) * Matrix[ b ]
# or equivalent
Matrix[ a ].transpose * Matrix[ b ]
```

Matrix is a part of Ruby stdlib and every serious Ruby speaker should learn its interface.