# What does Ruby block return to?

Tags: ruby

Good day. I've tried writing this code in ruby

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x.each do |a|
    a + 1
end
```

When I type this in irb, I don't understand why does it return
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

I thought it would return
=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # because of a + 1

Comment: Difference between `each`, `map`, `map!` https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429114/16236820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#each-method) yields the array's elements to the given block (one after another) without modifying the array. At the end, it returns the array, as mentioned in the docs:

> [...] passes each successive array element to the block; returns `self`

You are probably looking for [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#map-method), which works similar to `each` but instead of returning `self`, it ...

> [...] returns a new Array whose elements are the return values from the block

Example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x.map { |a| a + 1 }
#=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note that it *returns* a new array without actually modifying `x`. There's also `map!` (with `!`) which *does* modify the receiver.

Comment: Thank you with your very clear answer. I perfectly understand it now..